# MongoDB query based on count of embedded document

Tags: filter, mongodb, count

Suppose I have:

```
Order: {_id: ..., items: [...]}
```

How to filter orders which have item number greater than 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the $where operator.

```
> db.orders.save({Order: {items: [1,2]}})                                                    
> db.orders.save({Order: {items: [1,2,3]}})
> db.orders.find({$where:function() { if (this["Order"]["items"].length > 2) return true; }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d334c9102bcfe450ce52585"), "Order" : { "items" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }
```

Two downsides of $where are that it can't use an index and the BSON object must be converted to a JavaScript object, since you are running a custom JavaScript function on every document in the collection.

So, $where can be very slow for large collections. But, for ad hoc or rarely run queries, it's extremely handy. If you frequently need to run queries like this, then you should follow Bugai13's recommendation, since you can then index the key in which you store the array size.

Comment: This could also be written a little shorter:

`.find({$where: "this.Order.items.length > 2"})`

Answer (score 6):

You cann't query by size of embed collection, you need to create field with size of collection for such needs(mongo db documentation):

> The $size operator matches any array
>   with the specified number of elements.
>   The following example would match the
>   object {a:["foo"]}, since that array
>   has just one element:
>
> db.things.find( { a : { $size: 1 } }
>   );
>
> You cannot use $size to find a range
>   of sizes (for example: arrays with
>   more than 1 element). If you need to
>   query for a range, create an extra
>   size field that you increment when you
>   add elements.

Comment: Also know the inverse, e.g.: `db.things.find( { a : { $not: { $size: 0 } } } );`

Answer (score 3):

To see if the length is greater than 5, you can test if a 6th element exists:

```
db.orders.find({"items.6": {$exists: true}})
```

This is much more efficient than using `$where`.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced this dilemma.  Not sure why it doesnt exist in MongoDB by default.  The most efficient way is to also store a property called `count` or `length` or something that denotes how many items are in the array.

Then you can index that property and do range queries on it.  It'll keep your queries simple and quick.

Just make sure that your application keeps it in sync.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and this seems like the best approach but still it "feels" wrong. Always learned you shouldn't store values in a database that can be calculated (they may get out of sync). Do you agree or is this a very 
"SQL way" of thinking?

Comment: Totally agree but this is just one of the tradeoffs of using MongoDB.  It will be much better in the next release (2.2) which will contain the new aggregation framework.  The aggregation framework will allow you to calculate things on the fly.  Wont perform as well as pre-calculating and storing the values, but it alleviates the concerns of getting out of sync.  Another tradeoff to consider.  You can test these features out in the 2.1 branch.