# How to find Scorecards having more than 2 team participants in mongoid + rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

Hi i have following model

```
class Scorecard
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :team_participants
end
```

I want to find all the scorecards having more than 2 team_participants.
I have tried following

```
Scorecard.where('team_participants.count' => {"$gte" => 3}).count
```

But it didn't work for me.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705024/mongodb-query-based-on-count-of-embedded-document

Answer (score 1):

As  Per this google group discussion
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/oyNRf3hJ5Cc
it seems like it is not possible to count the length of a embed document in a where clause. But if you really need this feature you can do something like .

```
Scorecard.all.map{|c| c if c.team_participants.length >  3}).compact
```

But it will reduce the performance as it will search the whole document.

Alternatively you can check the link
[MongoDB query based on count of embedded document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705024/mongodb-query-based-on-count-of-embedded-document)

Answer (score 0):

The following test shows how to do what you want via the MongoDB aggregation framework.
However if choose to use this, carefully test its performance.
For higher performance with scaling, you should consider adding an explicit field like
team_participants_count that tracks the array size of team_participants,
and that explicit field can be used in normal queries.
If you try other solutions like '$where' referenced in other comments,
you should carefully measure their performance as well.

Enjoy!

test/unit/scorecard_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

class ScorecardTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Scorecard.delete_all
  end

  test "select by array size comparison" do
    docs = [
        {team_participants:[{name:'a'}]},
        {team_participants:[{name:'b'},{name:'c'}]},
        {team_participants:[{name:'d'},{name:'e'},{name:'f'}]},
        {team_participants:[{name:'g'},{name:'h'},{name:'i'},{name:'j'}]}
    ]
    Scorecard.create(docs)
    assert_equal(4, Scorecard.count)
    pp Scorecard.collection.aggregate(
        [{'$unwind' => '$team_participants'},
         {'$group' => {'_id' => '$_id',
                       'team_participants' => {'$push' => '$team_participants'},
                       'team_participants_count' => {'$sum' => 1},
                       'created_at' => {'$first' => '$created_at'},
                       'updated_at' => {'$first' => '$updated_at'}}},
         {'$match' => {'team_participants_count' => {'$gte' => 3}}}
        ])
  end
end
```

$ rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/1] ScorecardTest#test_select_by_array_size_comparison[{"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea5100000a",
  "team_participants"=>
   [{"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea5100000b", "name"=>"g"},
    {"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea5100000c", "name"=>"h"},
    {"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea5100000d", "name"=>"i"},
    {"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea5100000e", "name"=>"j"}],
  "team_participants_count"=>4,
  "created_at"=>2014-04-26 02:31:44 UTC,
  "updated_at"=>2014-04-26 02:31:44 UTC},
 {"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea51000006",
  "team_participants"=>
   [{"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea51000007", "name"=>"d"},
    {"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea51000008", "name"=>"e"},
    {"_id"=>"535b1a90a3f576ea51000009", "name"=>"f"}],
  "team_participants_count"=>3,
  "created_at"=>2014-04-26 02:31:44 UTC,
  "updated_at"=>2014-04-26 02:31:44 UTC}]
Finished tests in 0.031745s, 31.5010 tests/s, 31.5010 assertions/s.
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```